# How to add pager or how to limit terms `taxonomy_get_tree($vid)`?

Tags: drupal, tree, taxonomy

How to use pager or how to limit terms, when using `taxonomy_get_tree($vid)`?

I have this code for terms generation:

```
<?php
$vid = 2;
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);   
$max_depth = (!isset($max_depth)) ? count($children[$vid]) : $max_depth;

foreach ($terms as $term) {
if ($term->depth == 0) 
{  
print "" .l("<b>Auto Insurance for &nbsp;</b> " .$term->name,'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid, array('attributes' => array('title' => $term->name, ), 'html' => TRUE) ). "";

}}

?>
```

But there are thousands of terms or sub terms. Some pages are then loading more then 20 seconds. I need to improve this situation.

Can you advice me please? Do you know some solution? Pager, Jquery, Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Get for the terms for the current page

```
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'td')
  ->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->condition('td.vid', $vid)
  ->fields('td', array('tid'))
  ->orderBy('td.weight')
  ->limit($limit);
$query->join('taxonomy_term_hierarchy', 'th', 'td.tid = %alias.tid AND %alias.parent = 0');
$tids = $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed(0,0);
$terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', $tids);
```

Display the pager

```
theme('pager');
```

Comment: hi, thank you for answer, but...where exactly to put this code?